# display text on image on mouseover (hover)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```html
 <div class="team-area">
                    
                    
                  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qBcmJBrd/1.jpg" alt="" >
                
                    <div class="socials">
                        <a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="margin-top: 6px;"></i></a>
                        <!-- <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone" style="margin-top: 6px;"></i></a> -->
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="margin-top: 6px;"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h2>
                        GA <span>Founder</span></h2>
                    <h5>Rome, ON</h5>
                </div>
```

(without css of course). and what i want to do is add an affect where if you hover over it, it displays text over the image. I tried to dot it with `mouseover`, but it isn't what i want. can anyone help me do this?

Comment: like what do you have an example how it should look like??

Comment: why not do this with CSS? Can be easily done by using the `:hover`-selector. If you want to sue the JS `mouseover`  what have you tried so far?

Comment: See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4642212).

Comment: @KunalTanwar i've tried something like this http://jsfiddle.net/UqdVp/1/ and a few variations of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `:hover`selector to toggle the text-box from `display: none;` to `display: block/flex;`

```css
.hover-box {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.hover-box > div {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.hover-box:hover > div {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-box">
  <img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
  <div>Random Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay yes this is close. but how do i get it on top of the image? this just shows it below. and thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: define on top of the image

Answer (score 0):

Add a `title` attribute to your image tag.

```html
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qBcmJBrd/1.jpg" alt="" title="This text will be displayed on hover">
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.